# Is it permissible to pray in advance when work commitments prevent me from praying on time?

Tags: salat

My problem is that I cannot really pray on time. 
I live in Europe and I have to be at work at 8:30. I don't have a car and the company is quite far from the city center where there is a mosquee.

The evening I live my job at 18h and I arrive at home at 19h. So I miss 3 prayers.

So the only prayer I can do on time is the dawn's and the night's.

Is it possible to pray by advance? What should I do in my situation?

Comment: You can pray in your office take the prayer mat with you pray wherever you find a clean place.If I were at your place I might have left the job which keeps me away from my prayers. Or do the job till i find a new One.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I really struggled to find that job. I work in a factory. There is really no place around where I can pray.  I even thought to pray in the WC :( I couldn't.

Comment: @J.Doe May Allah Subhan o Taala bless you and guide you the way,well someone had the same problem like yours like working in a factory having  no clean area so I advised to pray in the car and now the problem is solved Alhumdulillah

Comment: Unfortunately, praying in office environnement is not accepted by others, I had a friend who is actually doing a PhD and she was told to not pray in office at university. So, please do consider this fact when you try to answer to OP's question. Also, quitting a job is not a solution, as it is so difficult to find another job;

Answer (score 2):

Islam is very peaceful religion and very easy to perform salah and others Arkaan but u should keep this thing in mind that u have to pray Salah even you are on bed and cant even stand. In different Ahadees we can see that how Sahaba's sacrifice their life for islam or a big Example of Hazrat Imam Hussain(R.A) who scarified their life, the time he was offering prayer. So

**1st Solution** is take your Prayer Mate(Musallah) with you when you go to office or factory. At Prayer time, Do wudu and place your mate somewhere (safe or clean place) in the factory and offer your prayer.

> Every non-muslims knows that muslims have to pray within the time
>   frame limit five times so you dnt need to keep others things in mind.

**2nd Solution**

You can trust any non-muslim in this matter that give you some space near where you can offer prayer. He will definitely help you.

**3rd Solution**

If you dont have any place for even your prayer mate(i dont think so its possible) , or even no one is helping you for offering prayer or even your manager is not allowing you to pray salah then in my opinion just leave your job. Because if your priority is Allah, then no power on earth can stop you to earn money or earn Jannah in AKhirah. Just Protect your Salah. It will take you where no one can even think. 
**Note:** : Read L**ahola wala Quwata Illa Billa** as much as u can. 
JazakAllah

Answer (score 0):

Between a muslim and a non-believer is his prayer.

This means that you should guard  your prayers with the utmost importance. You do not want to find that on the day of judgment that your job was your shirk, and find yourself among the non believers.

Islam has many ways to make this practice easy for you.

If the work is more than 24 miles away, so that traveling there and back will take you 48 miles then you should be shortening your prayers and this will make it easier.

In this case you can also combine your prayers (duhhr and asr, as well as magrib and isha)
This is not compulsory for a traveler but is something you can do if you have a good reason to do so.
To do this you would pick a time within the windows of Dhuhr and Asr
You would make your intention to pray Dhuhr and pray two rakat (Dhuhr is shortened due to traveling) then following that, make your intention to pray Asr and pray two rakat.

This is done in a similar way for Maghrib and Isha 
Though magrib is not shortened. 
If you arrive home before you've prayed Maghrib but it is time for isha, then you can still combine them, but do not shorten the Isha salah.

What this means is that you would only need to find one time for salah during  your travel to work or while you are at work.

Since you aren't very clear about what exactly is preventing you from salah I cant really help with that. But i know that amy situation Allah puts you in will present some instance in which you can keep your responsibility to Him.
Find a stair well or a parking lot or anyplace really.
Allah has made the entire world a place for salah.
If you really cannot find a place to do it, for a valid reason, i.e. Because you are afraid and not just because you are embarrassed,  then you can pray while on the bus.

May Allah make it easy for you and guide you to maintaining your salah.

Answer (score 0):

In Sahih Muslim , Hadith # 1516

Ibn 'Abbas reported: The Messenger of Allaah (sallAllaahu alayhi wa sallam) observed the noon and afternoon prayers together in Medina without being in a state of fear or in a state of journey. (Abu Zubair said: I asked Sa'id [one of the narrators] why he did that. He said: I asked Ibn 'Abbas as you have asked me, and he replied that he [the Prophet] wanted that no one among his Ummah should be put to [unnecessary] hardship.)

So, from the above Hadees, we can say

The five prayers

- Fajr
- Dhuhr and Asr (Separately or combined)
- Magrib and Isha (Separately or combined)

It is always recommended to perform 5 prayers separately, but if the person foreseeing the situation of Qadha it is recommended to combine Asar with Dhuhar (4+4 rakat) and Magrib with Isha (3+4 Rakat) better than making the Salat Qadha.

Note : Dhuhar + Asar can be 2+2 and Magrib + Isha can be 3+2 in some special cases like lengthy travel, etc.

So, we should find praying options at-least 3 times. The after noon prayer will be difficult for most of the workers, but there will be lunch time for any work, in this time we have to do it. If there is no place to do the prayer at lunch time, we should sit on some chair and do it. If there is no option to sit, we can stand somewhere and complete the prayer.

Allahu A'lam

Answer (score -1):

If you have missed Duhr, Asr, and Maghrib prayers and are having difficulty you have some options.  You can make up the prayers when you return back home.  So you can do 4 rakats, then 4 rakats, then 3 rakats, but for the 3 rakats, you would do tahashud(pointing finger) and complete the prayer on the 3rd rakat.  You cannot pray like you are praying Maghrib, once Maghrib is missed, it’s missed.  The second option is to ask your employer if you can do earlier shifts if possible and see what he/she says.
The third option is to look for another job while you are doing your job and apply to another company that has a better time schedule and also maybe let you pray at the masjid (mosque).  If you are business minded, the last option would be to save up money and take a short certificate or diploma program and start up your own small business.  Inshallah, things should work out for you.

Asalamaleikum

Comment: " then 3 rakats, but for the 3 rakats, you would do tahashud(pointing finger) and complete the prayer on the 3rd rakat" I've never heard this do you have a reference?

Comment: The reference is in Sahih Bukhari in the Book of Prayers.  Our Prophet SAW did Maghrib prayer as a special prayer for Allah to answer his duas(supplications).  When the nights were very rainy and he missed Maghrib and Isha time came, he would pray 7 rakats (combine the Maghrib and Isha prayers) but didn't pray them as he would pray Maghrib. Reference Sahih al-Bukhari 543 In-book reference  : Book 9, Hadith 20, USC-MSA web (English) reference  : Vol. 1, Book 10, Hadith 518.  If you go to sunnah.com, all the information about our Prophet SAW is there.  Asalamaleikum

Comment: This is a known but the practice is to pray al-maghrib 3 and then al-'isha 4 with a salam and a short interruption to do iqama for 'isha! What you said isn't included in that hadith! 7 and 8 in the hadith is the sum of the raka'at of two -separated- prayers! And as the narrator named the prayers clearly this means they have been prayed separatly!

Answer (score -1):

You are already praying 2 times (dawn's and night's). You can pray at noon while you are walking or sitting in somewhere. That's what I have done in such conditions. 
Do not search for another job for this reason, that makes no sense!
I think you are exaggerating things.

See these 2 verses (Surah 2 Baqarah verses 288-299):

"Guard the prayers, and the middle prayer, and stand up to Allah truly devout."

"And if ye fear, then pray on foot or riding; then when ye are secure, remember Allah in the way He hath taught you which ye ever knew not"

Using your logic and reading Qoran will guide you well.

Answer (score -1):

If you can’t pray standing pray sitting at your desk! If there is no place in the factory to prostrate then do prostration in the air! And if you are in hospital pray laying down in bed!  But there is no excuse for missing any prayer whatsoever! This is your right to Allah! Do it on time in the best manner you can! And Allah doesn’t ask a sole more than it can bear!

Answer (score -2):

You can Short the Prayer, or you also can pray to respect the time (even you has no wudhu' at all). Then, qada' back at home. 
TThat's what I learned. If there's mistakes, do correct me please. Thanks!